# Link to official JavaEE 8 API docs

Tags: jakarta-ee

Here is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/index.html) official Oracle documentation.

But official Oracle web-site does not contain JavaEE 8 documentation, while JavaEE 8 was released in 2017.

I know that Java extends is given to Eclipse and renamed Jakarta EE.  But I could not find a link to API and tutorials.

My problem was - I wanted to see API of HttpServletRequest interface in JavaEE 8, besides I wanted to download javadoc for java EE 8 (javax.servlet.http package classes, etc)

Comment: One of first "java ee 8 documentation" google hits https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/ or even https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the project is now hosted on github : https://javaee.github.io/

- [Java-ee 8 tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/toc.html)
- [Javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/)